# PowerShell Writing To Word, dynamically calculating Padding for alignment

Tags: powershell, ms-word, padding

I am trying to write to word two different addresses (say from my address to my friends address) but I want the text at the far ends of the document. But calculating the padding so that its exactly at the end is not consistent. I have been trying with the example below but cannot find a consistent calculation. Does anyone see a pattern that can help me? (Take into consideration that the left will never change, always ThisTextIs12).
The From and To are hardcoded to be exactly right and I worked off that but it didn't work out.
183 is max characters a line in word can have (characters, not spaces).

From PowerShell:

```
$first = "ThisTextIs12" # Length = 12
$second = "ThisTextIsABitLonger22" # Legnth = 22
$third = "only 6" # Length = 6
$savepath="C:\Users\Milan\Downloads\test.docx"
 
$word=new-object -ComObject "Word.Application"
#$Word.Visible = $True

$doc = $word.documents.Add() 
$myDoc = $word.Selection
 
$a = "From:".PadRight(176, ' ') + "To:" # exactly right: 183-5-3+1
$myDoc.TypeText($a)
$myDoc.TypeParagraph()

$b = $first.PadRight(183-([int]$first.Length+[int]$second.Length), ' ')+$second # needs to be 135 instead of 149, so remove 14
$b.Length
$myDoc.TypeText($b)
$myDoc.TypeParagraph()
$c = $first.PadRight(183-([int]$first.Length+[int]$third.Length), ' ')+$third # needs to be 166 instead of 165, so add 1
$c.Length
$myDoc.TypeText($c)
$myDoc.TypeParagraph()
 
$doc.SaveAs([ref]$savepath) 
$doc.Close() 
 
$word.quit()
```

From Word:

[image]

Comment: The only way to have this done is when Word uses a monospaced font (i.e. where every character, including the space has the same width). As you can see in your output, that is mostly not the case.. You will probably need a table for that, where you can set the alignment left/right for each table cell.

Comment: You can use a tabstop at the very right of the page and then set it to "Alignment: Right". Then, instead of putting lots of spaces between the From and To text on each line, you just insert a single tab (e.g. ```ThisTextIs12 [TAB] ThisTextIsABitLonger22```). That will left-align the "From" address lines and right-align the "To" address. It might be better overall though to do what @Theo suggests and insert a table with 1 row and 2 columns - it'll make a simpler and more logical document structure to edit later.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sclas.png for an example of a right-aligned tab-stop

Comment: @mclayton
thank you
Truth is i was trying to add tables before but I have trouble with it.
Because whenever I add tables, it overwrites the text.
My structure needs to be: 
Title
Table
other text
Not sure how to do those. Got any links?